# What are the Fourier coefficients of multiplying a function with the derivative of another function?

Tags: fourier-series

Consider a Fourier series
$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} C_n e^{j n \omega_0 t}$. Let's assume $\mathrm{x}_1(\mathrm{t}) {\leftrightarrow} \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{n}},  \mathrm{x}_2(\mathrm{t}){\leftrightarrow} \mathrm{D}_{\mathrm{n}}$. Then we know that $\mathrm{x}_1(\mathrm{t}) \cdot \mathrm{x}_2(\mathrm{t}) {\leftrightarrow} \sum_{\mathrm{k}=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{k}} \mathrm{D}_{\mathrm{n}-\mathrm{k}}$. But how about $\mathrm{x}_1(\mathrm{t}) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{x}_2(\mathrm{t}) $ ? Is it $\mathrm{x}_1(\mathrm{t}) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{x}_2(\mathrm{t}) {\leftrightarrow} \sum_{\mathrm{k}=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{k}}.(in\omega_0). \mathrm{D}_{\mathrm{n}-\mathrm{k}}$ ?

Comment: You seem to be using both $j$ and $i$ to mean the same thing. Anyway, you can use your formula but with $D_n$ replaced by $(in\omega_0)D_n$, which means that $D_{n-k}$ should be replaced by $(i(n-k)\omega_0)D_{n-k}$. So it would be $\sum_{\mathrm{k}=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{k}}.(i(n-k)\omega_0). \mathrm{D}_{\mathrm{n}-\mathrm{k}}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.